# Video Analysis to detect Object [ Realtime ]

Tags: opencv, video, image-processing, object-detection

I want to do video analysis to detect movement for a certain duration in time. For example, I have a video of my lane outside my house. I want to check whether it remains clean. So, i wanted to detect garbage lying around(and in case it is being cleaned). I tried a lot of sites, they said that I will have to take the video and divide it into frames and XOR the frames and find out the object movement.

I tried to find example code for this and I was unable to find the same. So if anybody has expertise in this field using OpenCV/Xuggler/JavaCV/ or any software and some code, can u please post so i can get going.

My main objective is to develop some software through which i can do realtime tracking of the garbage outside my house and check who is dumping it, and whether it is being cleaned. Is it possible? Any ideas/suggestions/ advice is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

I've tried OpenCV, but have no clue how to split video into frames and apply object detection on it.

Thanks!

Comment: [OpenCV How to Use Background Subtraction Methods](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of background Subtraction based technique. If there is any change in the background (which your lane in this case), you would be able to detect it.

You should have a sample code of "Background subtraction" provided by openCV samples.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{

    VideoCapture cap;
    bool update_bg_model = true;

    cap.open(0);
    cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;//(100, 3, 0.3, 5);
    bg.set ("nmixtures", 3);
    std::vector < std::vector < cv::Point > >contours;

    cv::namedWindow ("Frame");
    cv::namedWindow ("Background");

    Mat frame, fgmask, fgimg, backgroundImage;

    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        bg.operator()(frame, fgimg);
        bg.getBackgroundImage (backgroundImage);
        cv::erode (fgimg, fgimg, cv::Mat ());
        cv::dilate (fgimg, fgimg, cv::Mat ());

        cv::findContours (fgimg, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        cv::drawContours (frame, contours, -1, cv::Scalar (0, 0, 255), 2);

        cv::imshow ("Frame", frame);
        cv::imshow ("Background", backgroundImage);


        char k = (char)waitKey(30);
        if( k == 27 ) break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as your query about splitting a video into frames is concerned, then you should know that a video is nothing but a collection of several frames. So, whenever you use `VideoCapture capture(videoFilename);` in openCV, you are capturing a single frame/image from your video.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple with the aid of google's opencv & javacv libraries.The logic is simply grabb the frames from the webcam continuesly using a thread and perform a substraction between the 2 consequetive frames. If there is any change between the 2 frames , it will produes a white pixel.Black pixel indicates no change between the frames[no motion detected].The complete implementation can be found [at here](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui169/index.html)